# Cannot change textbox border color on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem:
Textbox border color changes only when I hover above the textbox. But I want to make it change the color when button is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
private void registracija_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
.
. 
.
         errorProvider2.SetError(RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt, "Username already exists!");              
         //RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Focus();
         RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Border.Color = Color.Red;
         RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Border.Thickness = 3; 
.
.
.
}
```

It shows errorProvider and it changes border thickness, but Color changes only when I hover above it.

Comment: `RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Invalidate()`?

Comment: Why does that work?

Comment: You typically have to signal that a control's visual needs to be updated, using either `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()`.  Otherwise, it may not be repainted.

Comment: `TextBox` doesn't have `Border` property. What is the control which you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void registracija_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
.
. 
.
     errorProvider2.SetError(RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt, "Username already exists!");              
     RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Invalidate();
     RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Border.Color = Color.Red;
     RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Border.Thickness = 3; 
.
.
.
}
```

**RegistracijaUporabnisko_txt.Invalidate();** - Solution! Thanks to [DonBoitnott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633308/donboitnott)